# MinGW multiple exe

Tags: c++, mingw, exe, msys

I've set up a MSYS + MinGW environment in order to build my software (C++).
I've successfully built it and in my folder I have now the .exe, but there is also a .libs folder with another .exe inside (much bigger, with the same name).

```
program.exe (~50kB)
.libs
   program.exe (~2MB)
```

The smaller exe works only if there is the .libs folder and the bigger exe; the other one works only if I put all the required dlls in its folder.
Which is the difference between these executables? Should i prefer ont or the other?
Thanks

EDIT:
I've built it with the help of the autotools.
The project is hosted here
https://github.com/Corna/pcb2gcode
It was .libs folder, typo

Comment: How exactly did you build that? That's no standard behavior of MinGW. Could it be there's one debug `.exe` and another release `.exe` was build? Or is it a test suite?

Comment: Makefile or build commands or console output of build would be helpful.

Comment: I've used the standard autotools commands: ./configure --prefix=[...] --with-boost=[...] and make